# OOo Sheet: Keep one cell reference constant when copying formulae

Tags: openoffice

First, I'm not sure if this is the right StackExchange site to be posting this on, although I've looked for better ones and couldn't find one. Anyway, my question is this: how can I keep a cell reference in a formula in OOo Sheet constant. What I mean by this is when you write say `=B6*A2` into a cell, and drag down, OOo (cleverly) increments all the cell references so you end up with `=B7*A3`. What I want to do, however, is keep `B6` as `B6` in each cell, while `A3` (and any other cells) can increment to their heart's content. Is this possible in OOo Sheet?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `B6` use `$B$6`.  The `$` in front of a row or column indicates that that row / column should remain fixed when copying forumlas.

Have a look at the [**OOo Formula page (Absolute Referencing section)**](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Calc_Guide/Creating_formulas#Absolute_referencing).

(btw - should be on superuser.com)

Comment: Thank you :-) Sorry for not posting it on SuperUser!

Comment: @JamWaffles No problem (on both accounts!) It'll get migrated to SuperUser, there are already 3 votes to do so, 5 are necessary.